# Boost pool malloc() and free() compiler error

Tags: c++, boost

I am using Boost 1.58 64bit, VC++ 2013 ,64bit project.Using boost::pool.

previously used Boost 1.54 and had no problems with calling:

```
 boost::pool  malloc()
```

and

```
 boost::pool free(p)
```

Now, both methods are throwing:

> error C2039: '_malloc_dbg' : is not a member of
>   'boost::pool'

and

error C2039: '_free_dbg' : is not a member of 'boost::pool'

accordingly.

Do I miss any directive to cause the compiler treat malloc and free as pool class members?

**UPDATE:**

I see it happens only inside the header inline methods.If I call them in .cpp I have no errors.

Example:

```
inline void* MemoryManager::AllocMemory(){

    return  m_pool->malloc();
}
```

throws compiler errors.

Comment: this will be some macro redefining malloc, try #undef malloc in the header

Comment: This looks like the issue but I would like to know if there is some less brutal force solution than using #undef (or maybe more brutal force :)  )

Comment: Not using shitty libraries that redefine `malloc` would be a start.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit if you look at boost::pool method you will see this is member and not macro function.Also I wouldn't call boost "a shitty library"

Comment: @MichaelIV: I didn't call Boost "a shitty library". You're using some other library that's redefining `malloc` as a macro, and _breaking_ this member in `boost::pool`. That's why you're getting a compilation error. Run your code through the preprocessor, and you'll see.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit no I don't man.Also,the only things changed from the previous version of my code which worked were VS version and the boost version.Didn't have this anomaly with VS2012 and boost 1.54

Comment: Sigh right okay you know best then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`crtdbg.h` from Windows contains the lines:

```
#ifdef  _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC

#define   malloc(s)             _malloc_dbg(s, _NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define   calloc(c, s)          _calloc_dbg(c, s, _NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define   realloc(p, s)         _realloc_dbg(p, s, _NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)
...
```

Try to `#undef _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC`

Edit: `#define _AFX_NO_DEBUG_CRT` should prevent `crtdbg.h` from being included. Add it to the project settings, or before including any Windows headers.

Comment: Interesting what @Lightness Races has to say about it.

Comment: Doesn't work either.Put it into Project Properties preprocessor.

Comment: And if you put it as the first line of `stdafx.h`, and clean+rebuild?

Comment: I don't use precompiled headers.

Comment: I will mark your answer as the correct one,but it still doesn't help in my case.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, sorry it didn't help. I guess you already tried to search for "#define malloc", or put the cursor on "malloc" and click "go to definition". (Because maybe it's defined somewhere else too...)